# Dynamic or runtime instance level metadadata in Java

Tags: java

How do we best design managing runtime metadata for a Java object?

Ex:

For a ORM like solution where a graph of object is persisted using a unified api. We may want to gather metadata like Expiry of an attribute.The sesssion expires after the preset amount of time

```
User
 |
 Session
```

Presently this can be approached with annotation,

```
User
 |
 |
  @Expire(3000)
  Session
```

But if we where to calculate Session expiry based on some other logic like depending on whether the server created the session during day or night. The above approach won't work.

Example 2:

1. The "Expire" is a framework offering and it could be used in
       multiple places in the same graph and in different ways.
2. Similarly the value of annotation is not known at design time/compile time. 
   Ex: Each user can choose their own password expiration.
    Similarly, It could be that session expiration is computed differently for each user

```
User
 |
 |
  @Expire
  password
 |
 |
  @Expire
  session
```

How best can we get this without making the expiry a field within the session? As a ORM we cannot distinguish the data from such special fields so this metadata has to be gathered at runtime.

Comment: Instead of adding a field, you could add a method which is called if required.  You could have an interface like `Expires`

Comment: Let me add few more information since the answers tend to solve particularly the example. As a framework developer, I want to be able to have the flexibility of capturing metadata at runtime

Answer (score 2):

You could have an interface `ExpiryManager` that would calculate this complex logic, then you could use the annotation like this:

```
@Expire(logic=MyExpiryManager.class)
Session
```

Annotations aren't limited to integer literals, but this is more about how weird you want to design the API.

Comment: +1 You can store meta data as a String and parse it however you like e.g. method names with arguments/expressions as well as classes.

Comment: I am having to have the users just expose a class with getter/setter classes in some cases.